# Different environments not working in NestJS

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-config

I would like to create a new environment for testing my app. I have a `.env` file and `.env.test` file.

This is my `app.module.ts` file:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      envFilePath: !process.env.NODE_ENV
        ? '.env'
        : `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'postgres',
      host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
      port: parseInt(<string>process.env.POSTGRES_PORT),
      username: process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
      password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
      database: process.env.POSTGRES_DATABASE,
      autoLoadEntities: true,
      entities: [User],
      synchronize: true,
    }),
    AuthModule,
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

The problem here is that `.env.test` is never called, `.env` always runs even though `process.env.NODE_ENV` returns `test`.
And this is how i set up my `package.json` file:

```
 "start:test": "NODE_ENV=test nest start --watch",
```

This is how my `.env.test` file looks like

```
POSTGRES_HOST=localhost
POSTGRES_PORT=5432
POSTGRES_USER=postgres
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=Random
POSTGRES_DATABASE=db-test
```

I also tried to hardcode `envFilePath: '.env.test',` and it still not working. For `.env.test` file to work i have to rename `.env` file and then it works fine.

**UPDATE!**

It works now. What i did was i put

```
ConfigModule.forRoot({
      envFilePath: !process.env.NODE_ENV
        ? '.env'
        : `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
    }),
```

in every module i have in my app.

Comment: How do you know that `.env.test` is not read?

Comment: because tables are not created in test database.

Comment: But you're using `process.env` directly instead of using the `ConfigService` from `@nestjs/config`, right? So how do _you_ populate `process.env` with the values from `.env.test`

Comment: I updated my post so it includes what i have in my `.env.test` file, if that is what you meant.  But i will look into `ConfigService`.

Comment: Make sure you don't have these variables defined at the OS level — they take precedence over those specified in the `.env` file. Another issue might be that the Nest CLI does not allow you to override the `NODE_ENV` variable, you could try a different name. Otherwise your setup works and is in fact something I'm using as well.

Comment: My `.env` and `.env.test` are defined at the root of the project. By different name you mean something like  `NODE_ENV_V` and i change to this new name in `package.json` file and in `app.module.ts` file.

Answer (score 0):

As you're using the `ConfigModule` presumably from `@nestjs/config` you should be using the `TypeormModule`'s `forRootAsync` method to make sure you use the read `.env` file.

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      envFilePath: !process.env.NODE_ENV
        ? '.env'
        : `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: (config: ConfigService): PostgresConnectionOptions => ({
        type: 'postgres' as const,
        host: config.get('POSTGRES_HOST'),
        port: parseInt(config.get('POSTGRES_PORT')),
        username: config.get('POSTGRES_USER'),
        password: config.get('POSTGRES_PASSWORD'),
        database: config.get('POSTGRES_DATABASE'),
        autoLoadEntities: true,
        entities: [User],
        synchronize: true,
      }),
    }),
    AuthModule,
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Thanks i think this is the right way to do it, but i get this long error in `useFactory`.

Comment: Can you add the error to a pastebin or similar? It's probably something like a missed type on my part

Comment: Here it is: https://pastebin.com/kJmSi0eN

Comment: The `.env` file is guaranteed to be loaded into `process.env` after the `ConfigModule.forRoot()` call in this setup. Both `dotenv` and `dotenv-expand` are synchronous and the latter modifies `process.env`. This asynchronous trickery is not necessary.

Comment: @Joulukuusi but nothing guarantees that `ConfigModule.forRoot()` (and the subsequent configuration called by `ConfigService`'s `constructor` is called _before_ `TypeormModule.forRoot()` is called. This is why we, the Nest team, encourage the use of `forRootAsync` and the dependency on the `ConfigService` in a factory

Comment: @Krneki123 the `type: 'postgres' as const` should have ensured that the `PostgresConnectionOptions` type was used, but for some reason it wasn't, I've added the type assertion for the `useFactory` return type, if that doesn't fix it then add `as PostgresConnectionOptions` at the end of the factory return. Strange that Typescript is bugging out on this

Comment: Thanks for your help but its not generating tables in database. What is also strange is if i hardcode `envFilePath: '.env.test',` it still not working. It only works if i rename `.env` to something else then `.env.test` generates tables in my test database.

Comment: That seems very strange. If you could provide access to your repo I'd like to take a look

Comment: Sorry i can't share my repo. But i quickly created a new nest app and i did everything like i have in my original post and it worked. So i now i have to find why is it not working in my project. But thanks for your help!